# How to upload videos to s3 bucket using React Native

Tags: react-native, amazon-s3, video-streaming

How to upload video files into s3 bucket using React Native. Now I am currently making an app and I can upload images into s3 bucket but I don't know how to upload video files into s3 bucket. I would like to know how to do that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

After updating to RN 0.57 we also ran into a problem where we could not upload videos as we did. 
We then used this package:

[react-native-aws3](https://github.com/benjreinhart/react-native-aws3)

It is old but works on both ios and android. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload files to S3 in multiple ways

1. using AWS-SDK by creating a buffer of files and uploading it directly
2. You can create a read stream and then upload the stream to the s3 bucket
3. You can go with pre-signed URL feature of AWS S3

Answer (score -2):

You need a library to access you files first, after you accessed the video file then you upload this way:

```
const form = new FormData();
const video = this.state.video;
form.append("video", {
  uri: video.uri,
  type: video.type,
  name: video.fileName
});
//build payload packet
var postData = {
  method: 'POST',
  body: form,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
  },
}
fetch('/post_url', postData)
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  }).then((responseJson) => {
    console.log('responseJson', responseJson);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('error', error);
  });
```

Comment: The solution ignores the context of the question.